# Recurrence Equation for new Algorithm of Factorial

Tags: algorithm, recursion, mergesort, factorial

I am looking for a recursive algorithm to evaluate what I call Factorial(m,n)=m*m+1*...*n, for every m

I appreciate any help.

What is the complexity of this algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `T(n, m)` be the time complexity of `Factorial(n, m)`.

Let `g(n) = Factorial(n, 1)` and `T"(n)` be the time complexity of `g(n)`, then:

`T(n, m) <= T"(n) + T"(m - 1)` for any `n, m`

and `T"(n) = T"(n - 1) + O(1)` which is `O(n)`.

To sum up, `T(n, m) = O(n) + O(m - 1) = O(n + m)`

Comment: your solution seems strange for me! Note that the number of multiplications is n-m. So, why O(n+m)?

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan you removed the code that OP posted. My answer is an analysis of that code

Comment: Sorry @pkacprzak, I didnt remove anything. I think I dont even have reputation to make this kind of edition (I guess). I just included some words in the question to make it clear. However, I dont understand the reason, they disappeared as well. When I try to edit again, the words I wrote are there. Then I cancel it and I cant see anything again. Maybe you can solve the problem making a second edition. I dont have reputation. There were something about dividing the n-m in two halves... Now the algorithm I wrote does not make any sense. It is possible to write a much simpler solution for this.

Comment: I just discovered that I am able to see the edition. It realy seems that I did it, but I didnt at least conciously. Something strange happened. I will try to fix it.

Comment: I tried but I couldnt undo that (I dindt know how). Can you solve this, please?

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan I suggest to wait for the OP to edit the question. I've checked the edit history and he posted two different source codes, so it's hard to figure it out what is he really asking for.

Comment: who is OP? Is it an alias for who wrote the question?

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan yes, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79804/whats-stackexchange-ese-for-op

Comment: thank you! Sorry for anything. I can see that some text was removed in my edition, but I don't know exactly what happened. I am having connection problems with stackoverflow since morning.

Answer (score 0):

Its will have recurrence equation T(n) = T(n-1) + 2 , In case of function call of Factorial(n,1)